# Find a local minimum in a 2-D array

Tags: algorithm

Given an N-by-N array a of N<sup>2</sup> distinct integers, design an O(N) algorithm to find a local minimum: an pair of indices *i* and *j* such that:

- `a[i][j] < a[i+1][j]`
- `a[i][j] < a[i-1][j]`
- `a[i][j] < a[i][j+1]`
- `a[i][j] < a[i][j-1]`

I found this question in a an online algorithm book, [Introduction to Programming in Java, chapter 4.2: Sorting and Searching](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/42sort/).

It is similar to problem 35 (same page):

- Given an array of N real numbers, write a static method to find in logarithmic time a local minimum (an index *i* such that `a[i-1] < a[i] < a[i+1]`).

It has some sort of binary search based solution which I am not able to find out.

Comment: anuja: 1-diensional case in logarithmic time: Ask for A[N/2]. If it is larger than A[1], you have a local minimum within first half. If it is larger than A[n], you have a local minimum within the second half. Otherwise, if A[N/2]<A[N/2-1],A[N/2+1] you have a local minimum at N/2. Otherwise, if A[N/2]>A[N/2+1], you have a local minimum within second half, and for A[N/2]>A[N/2+1] you have a local  minimum within first half. Draw pictures to be convinced...

Comment: To help understand the solution to problem 35 (and possibly this one), please note that you're not searching for *the* minimum, only *a* local minimum.

Comment: __The problem is misstated__ (see my answer).  Edge cells are left undefined.  If edge cells __cannot__ be local minima than there is no solution.  If edge cells __can__ be local minima, than you can use a divide-and-conque solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same problem is mentioned in web version of book [Algorithms by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne. (See "Creative problems" section, problem 19)](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/).

The hint for the problem given by author in [that link](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/) is:

**Find the minimum in row N/2, check neighbors p and q in column, if p or q is smaller then recur in that half.**

*A better aprroach would be :
Find the minimum in row N/2, check all entries in its column, if we get smaller entry in column, then recur in the row where smaller column entry belongs.*

eg. 
For array below, N=5:

```
1  12  3   1  -23  
7   9  8   5   6
4   5  6  -1  77
7   0  35 -2  -4
6  83  1   7  -6
```

Step 1: The middle row is [`4   5  6  -1  77`]. ie. row number 3.

Step 2: Minimum entry in current row is `-1`.

Step 3: Column neighbors for min entry (ie. `-1`) are `5` and `-2`. `-2` being the minimum neighbor. Its in the 4th row.

Continue with steps 2-3 till we get the [local min](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LocalMinimum.html).

**EDIT:**

For example mentioned in comment from @anuja
*(the main problem is for n-by-n array. This input is 3-by-4 array but we can work with that)* :

```
1 2 3  4 
5 1 6 -1
7 3 4 -2
```

Step 1: The middle row is `[5 1 6 -1]`. ie. row number 2.

[image]

Step 2: Minimum entry in current row is `-1`.

[image]

Step 3: Column neighbors for min entry (ie. `-1`) are `4` and `-2`. 
`-2` is the minimum column neighbor. Its in the 3rd row.

[image]

Iterating to Step 2: -2 is smallest in its row and smallest amongst its column neighbours. So we end with -2 as output for local minimum.

[image]

Comment: This is n^2 in the worst case.  Consider an array that consists of a descending set of numbers going back and forth with each row separated by a wall of higher numbers.  You will loop n*(n/2)/2 times to follow the chain to it's end.  I think if we add a step after your #2 of repeating 1, 2 on the column containing the low value and then proceed with your 2, 3 loop that it's O(n).

Comment: This algorithm is a bit cutesy, but it is not O(n). Finding the minimum in a row is O(n).
The amount of times that we have to find a row minimum can be dependent on n (for some matrix patterns).
It's possible to construct a matrix which forces the algorithm to visit all rows and columns. Consider the
matrix with the rows: `8 3 4 8`, `8 8 8 7`, `8 8 5 6` and `1 2 8 8`. Your algorithm would visit all rows and all columns,
making it an `O(n^2)`algorithm. (So, for this input matrix, simply looping through all elements and finding the minimum
element in the whole matrix would be more efficient)

Comment: You're answer is confusing because the first approach is not bad but wrong. I struggled for over 3 hours until I found out, why it's not working. There are some edgecases where you have to do what you call the "better approach". Example in which taking the middle row/col is not working (N=5): `10, 8, 9, 12, 11` `9, 7, 8, 9, 0` `10, 6, 9, 6, 1` `12, 5, 4, 3, 2` `13, 9, 7, 8, 10` (In my exercise there is only one global minimum). For this example the algorithm get's stuck in the upper left corner (because of `7, 8, 9`...)

Comment: @Chaoste, I don't understand what goes wrong with your example.  If we start in the middle row (`10 6 9 6 1`), the smallest is `1`.  We look at its neighbors and discover the neighbor above (`0`) is smaller, so we move to the 2nd row (`9 7 8 9 0`).  We discover its smallest is `0`, and we look at its neighbors and see that `0` is a local minimum, so we are done.  The algorithm outputs `0`, and that *is* indeed a local minimum.  So on this test case the algorithm seems to output the correct answer, and doesn't get stuck in the upper-left corner.  Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: (Note that this question is about finding a local minimum, not a global minimum.)

Comment: @D.W. But if we want to satisfy all of the conditions given in OP, then in that case above approach will not work, right ?  If we consider the example as: ```{4,  3,  1,  14, 16 },
{10, 12, 5,  7,  8  },
{4,  6,  7,  4,  8  },
{10, 8,  12, 14, 10 },
{5,  10, 12, 5,  10}```
Then in this case if we go by the approach given above, then answer will be 4 which is at position (2,0). But if we look to satisfy all the condition then the real answer is 5 which is at position (2,3).
Am I missing some logic here ?

Comment: Does the line `(assuming the neighboring entry is in bounds).` has some meaning as given in [19 creative problem](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/)

Comment: @AshwinK, yes, you are missing something.  There are multiple valid answers.  4 at position (2,0) is a valid answer.  5 at position (4,3) is also a valid answer.  Both of those satisfy all the requirements in the question.

Comment: What if, For each row 'n' we do a binary search to find the local minima(O(log(n)), and for the columns 'n' in the matrix it would take O(n*log(n)). Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5):

**Update**:  This answer is assuming that edges are not local minima, as they are not defined as such by the four comparisons in the original problem statement.  In this case this answer is correct (it is not possible).  If you redefine the question such that edges can be local minima, than every matrix contains at least one local minima - and hence you can use a a divide-and-conquer approach.

**If edge cells cannot be local minima:**

There is no solution to the question as stated.  An N-by-N array takes O(N^2) time just to read the elements.  As there could be a single local minimum "hiding" anywhere in the matrix, this is provably necessary to do.

If you meant to ask for an O(N^2) algorithm, than simply walking each element and comparing it to its 4 neighbours takes O(N^2) time.

Either you have misremembered the interview question (and there was more to it), or this is just a trivial coding exercise.

**Proof**:

```
1. Construct a NxN matrix such that each cell has the value M[i,j] = N*i + j.
2. Select a random x,y (1 < x < N and 1 < y < N) and assign M[x,y] = -1
```

This matrix has exactly one local minima (M[x,y]), and its location is **independent** of the values in the other cells.  Therefore the other cells provide **no information** about its location, and so it is impossible to have any system to search for it that has better than an expected (N^2/2) cells searched = O(N^2).

(In other words you may as well be searching a near all zero matrix M[i,j] = 0 except for M[x,y] = -1 for the minima.)

This proof depends on being able to construct a matrix with no local minima in step 1.  **If edge cells are possible local minima than every matrix must have one,** and this proof no longer holds.

Answer (score 2):

Visit a random cell. If any of its four neigbors have a smaller value: go to that cell. If none of the neigbors are smaller, you are in a local minimum. Will be a bit harder to avoid loops if cells with equal values are possible.

Update:

Instead of visiting one neigbor, we could pick the smallest neigbor.

The most difficult topology seems to be the case of two "concentric" spirals, one of them functioning as a spiralling dike. That would in the worst case still take about N/2 steps. (with N=number of cells.)

Comment: In general, it is not (you could create a "spiral" forcing to visit O(N^2) cells in expectation)

Comment: What do you do if you reach an edge?

Comment: Though it is not O(n), the steepst ascent approach will probably be more effective then a brute-force search.

Comment: This is not bad.  The real flaw in it though is that you are not at all guaranteed to have *any* local minima.  Or for any that do exist to be find-able by any "local" procedure that is two or more cells away from it.

Comment: @sdcvvc Can you give a specific example of a spiral?

Comment: fgb 9 51 -3  -2 -1 / 8 52 -4  56  0 / 7 53  54 55  1 / 6 5   4   3  2 Rectangular, but I hope the idea is clear. Large numbers over 50 forbid "shortcuting" the spiral.

Comment: What if instead of starting at a random cell, start at the smallest value in the middle row?

Comment: I know nothing about the complexity of this method. But given that *only one* local minimum is required, and assuming a "reasonable" distribution of values, it probably won't need to visit all the cells.

Comment: @wildplasser:  You *PROBABLY* won't need to visit them all but you can end up with n*(n/2) cells visited if you start at the very start of a long path.  Note that the path can also be switchbacks.